# Knot to tie a hook onto the middle of a line

Tags: fishing, knots

If I have a fishing line that's secured at both ends, what knot would I use to tie a hook onto the line?
 My situation is I'm making some rigs for fishing behind a boat, with 10 hooks spaced a foot apart. I don't want to use clip on hooks, or to pull ten feet of line through a knot ten times. Or I already have a rig that I want to add more lures to without cutting the line.
 Perhaps it impossible to tie a circle onto a line with both ends fixed, using no extra pieces of line. If this is the case, then a topological explanation showing why will answer my question.

Comment: Search for "Dropper knot"

Comment: I am not exactly sure about your requirements: Should it be possible to add more hooks to your line while it is fixed at both ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used a standard [Palomar](http://www.animatedknots.com/palomar/) knot before.

Pass a loop through the eye of the hook.  Tie the loop into a standard overhand knot.  Pass the hook through the loop.  Tighten the loop and knot.

There's no rule that says the loop HAS to be at the end of the line.

Answer (score 8):

### [Dropper Loop Knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/dropperloop/index.php?Categ=fishing&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint)

1. Tie Dropper knots at the points where you want hooks.

[image: Dropper Loop Knot]

2. Tie your hooks to a short length of line and put a [perfection loop](http://www.animatedknots.com/perfection/index.php?Categ=fishing&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint) in the other end.

[image: Perfection Loop]

3. Connect the hooks to the short lines to the main line by first feeding the dropper loops through the perfection loops, then the hooks through the dropper loops, just like putting a new leader on your float line.

[image]

Comment: As both you, Desorder and mattnz mentioned the dropper knot: What makes this knot ideal for this case? There is a ton of knots to make a small loop midline. One advantage I see: It is easy to untie, but e.g. a butterfly is too and seems easier to me (much less windings needed).

Comment: And please add your image sources, the first two are clearly from animatedknots.

Comment: @imsodin One does not simply tie normal knots into fishing line and expect them to stay tied. A butterfly knot will not keep it's loop in fishing line. Fishing knots aren't meant to be untied, the struggle with fishing line is tying a knot that won't come undone.

Comment: @imsodin I already link to both pages on knog where those images came from.

Comment: @ShemSeger Please still mention where the images come from, as not all people will follow links and the site might be down at times and it is the rules to give sources.

Comment: @Willeke I was under the assumption everyone was familiar with knots by grog. All his images are so easy to identify. If you're a knotter, you'll love his app: https://www.animatedknots.com/iphonedetails.php

Comment: Us knot tyers do know his site and app, but most people who will read this question and its answers will not be as familiar with him. (I did link to his site in an answer today.)

Comment: @ShemSeger thanks for this solution, but as I said in the original question I don't want to use any additional pieces of line to attach my hook to the main line. Nice try tho :)

Comment: @Nic Actually you don't appear to have said any such thing in the question. I just looked again and still did not see it. You said you don't want a clip on hook and you do not want to pull lots of line through every time. This answer does neither of those things. This fully answers the question that was asked. Nice try tho ;)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how it would perform with a fishing line but maybe the [Directional (Inline) Figure 8 Loop](http://www.animatedknots.com/fig8directional/index.php?Categ=typemidloops&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint) may do the trick. :)

[image: Directional Inline Figure eight]

I use it a lot to tie people half way the rope.

Comment: On a wet, thin nylon line, I have a feeling figure of eight's tend to work themselves loose.

Comment: @Nic Yeah, that's why I put the disclosure Re the fishing line.

Comment: Downvoted, not a fishing-line knot.

Comment: @Beanluc fair... I don't do any fishing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an alpine butterfly knot, they can be tied in the bight and are very stable:

https://www.flyfishing.co.uk/general-fly-fishing-discussion/254018-alpine-butterfly-knot-dropper-loop.html

Comment: While stable, these knots are best suited to climbing carabiners which clip to the loop. The closed nature of a hook eye requires a knot that includes the eye in the trying process. Of course, one can always include the knot via a larks head, but this effectively defeats the purpose of the knot tied to generate the loop for the larks head.